# internet connection monitor

Tags: linux, connection, network-monitoring

I am looking for a tool to check my internet connection (by pinging something and/or retrieving a web page) and when the connection is lost to execute some command (sending an e-mail, resetting my router, sending a SMS).

It would be nice if it also creates reports/graphs on how well the connection is doing but I am not interested in bandwidth monitoring.

I can make something myself using bash or perl but I was wondering if there are existing tools to do this. I could not find one.

Comment: I hope that email you want to send will be internal. I don't like your chances of it reaching a remote destination if your Internet connection is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of one tool to do it all, but ..

[Smokeping](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) will do some nice graphs.  And you can setup [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) to do the connection monitoring and then setup an [event handler](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/eventhandlers.html) to execute your command(s) on failure.

Comment: Smokeping looks good for the graphs but for the monitoring I just use some perl. That was quicker than installing and learning how to configure nagios.